# How to Submit Form data like files and text in Dynamic jquery form builder to C# Action method MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, formbuilder

I am using jquery Form Builder From for create Dynamic Form Creation for template purposes and use much time on my web site. Those forms but I am stuck in File Submission.

I don't know how to submit generated form with file upload Form builder give me only json `## Heading ##` Result and file name into my json and I don't know how to upload File in my back end?